# Inserting Dynamically Facebook Pixel Passed as Query in Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-tag-manager, facebook-pixel

I have multiple Facebook Pixels ID that will be passed as URL parameters (i.e. first pixel 'fbpid=123456789' - second pixel 'fbpid=987654321' etc.)

Here's how the entire pixel scripts looks like:

```
<script>
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
{if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window, document,'script',
'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
fbq('init', 'PIXEL_ID');
fbq('track', 'PageView');
fbq('track', 'Lead');
</script>
```

Whenever a user clicks a certain button, if the URL parameter is fbpid=12345679, I would need to replace the PIXEL_ID inside the script above with the fbpid=12345679 passed as a query so that only the pixel ID 123456789 is fired.

Instead, for instance, if the pixel ID in the URL parameter is fbpid=987654321 then only the pixel with the ID 987654321 should be fired, and so on.

How can I insert the PIXEL_ID dynamically into the code above using Google Tag Manager?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using a lookup table variable:

1. Create a URL Variable  using the Query component type with the query
   key 'fbpid' - (if this is a Click URL then click more settings and
   then choose 'click url' - if not choose your setting or leave blank for a simple page url)
2. Create a Lookup table variable
3. Use the variable you just created as your input variable
4. Use the FB ID as your Input
5. Use your pixel ID as your Output
6. Call on the Lookup table you just created in your HTML Facebook tag you've shown above in the appropriate place

[LU TABLE IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKn0f.png)

I hope this helps